# Do any systems have more than one planetoid capable of supporting life?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends

Are there any examples in the Star Wars universe of a star system containing more than one planet/moon/whatever capable of supporting life?

Clarifications:

- To be "capable of supporting life", the natural ecosystem can support any kind of biological life with little to no technological assistance. Requiring constant technological assistance to breathe within the atmosphere does not count. Being capable of breathing in the atmosphere for a certain length of time, and then needing some technological assistance to recover (like, say, correcting some chemical imbalances from the alien atmosphere) counts.
- Related to above, celestial objects that require an installation to provide an atmosphere do not count.
- Terraformed planets/moons/whatevers count (this is the only exception to the first bullet).
- The life on the planet need not be sentient. If a known planet only consists of vegetation, that's ok.
- The planet need not be capable of supporting human life.
- The examples of biological life should be readily apparent. If you can visibly see the organisms with the naked eye and without scientific analysis, then it counts.
- Life on a planet does not need to inhabit the surface. Cloud City is a good example if the system it resides in meets the rest of the criteria.
- The planets/system need not still exist. The Alderaan system could still count if it satisfies the other criteria.

I'd prefer Disney canon examples, but I strongly suspect the aren't any. So I'll accept examples from Legends that are noted as such.

Comment: Hosnian system from The Force Awakens might qualify if it can be established whether or not they were using artificial life support tech on the various moons/planets. Perhaps the novel has some detail on that?

Comment: Do moon-sized space stations count?  If so, there's the pretty obvious pair of Endor and the second Death Star.

Comment: Hoth and Bespin. After all, the Falcon was able to fly from one to the other without having a functional hyperdrive, so they *must* be in the same system, no? ;-)

Comment: @DarrelHoffman: The Death Star doesn't count since it's atmosphere is artificially contained (with walls and ceilings) since it is essentially a military installation. Starkiller base certainly counts, though, if there's another celestial body that houses life. But, that raises an excellent question: what about an artificial moon/planet with an open atmosphere that supports life? I'd have to consider that situation, but I probably won't unless someone comes up with an example to force the issue.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In terms of Disney Canon examples, there aren't that many.

- **Trandosha and Kashyyyk** appear to be in the same system as each other (mentioned in Clone Wars episode 'Wookiee Hunt' as well as the "Ultimate Star Wars" factbook, but interestingly *not* on the [Star Wars website](https://www.starwars.com/databank/trandosha))
- The [Star Wars: Commander](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Commander) game indicates that **Yavin** has 4 habitable moons
- There's a mention that the **Corellian** System has 5 planets (referred to as the "*Five Brothers*") in the Matthew Stover Novelisation of Revenge of the Sith. That being said, the conversation between Palpatine and Anakin didn't make it into the film, which makes it Legends-canon, rather than Disney-canon.

> “All right,” Anakin said softly. “Corellia. I’ll take Corellia.”
>
> “The planet, or the whole system?”
>
> Anakin stared.
>
> “Anakin?”
>
> “I just-” He shook his head blankly. “I can’t figure out if you’re
>   kidding, or completely insane.”
>
> “I am neither, Anakin. I am trying to impress upon you a fundamental
>   truth of our relationship. A fundamental truth of yourself’.”
>
> “What if I really wanted the Corellian system? The whole Five
>   Brothers-all of it?”
>
> “Then it would be yours. You can have the whole sector, if you like.”
>   The twin gleams within the shadow sharpened. “Do you understand, now?
>   I will give you anything you want.””

Comment: *Aftermath* - Ryloth and one of its moons are habitable.  Not sure if the moon was naturally habitable.

Comment: @WadCheber The moon is naturally habitable. The proof is in *Lords of the Sith*. I've posted it as an [answer](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/118051/31936). Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 6):

There is a canonical example: **Nar Shaddaa** (*Ultimate Star Wars*) is a habitable moon in orbit about **Nal Hutta** (*Clone Wars*), which is the home planet of the Hutts - so this means there are two habitable worlds in the Hutt home system.

There are also quite a few examples from *Legends* - of particular note is the Corellian system, which hosted five habitable worlds: Corellia, Selonia, Drall, Tralus, and Talus.

Comment: I'm struggling to see a canon confirmation that Nar Shaddaa is in the same system as Nal Hutta. What does it say in Ultimate Star Wars?

Answer (score 3):

In both canon and Legends, the most iconic example, in my opinion, is the Kashyyyk system, which bears both the Wookiee homeworld of [Kashyyyk](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Kashyyyk) and the Trandoshan homeworld of [Trandosha](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Trandosha). There is possibly no greater rivalry of species in the history of Star Wars than that between the Wookiees and the Trandoshans, nor one as well illustrated and published. One can say they are yet another manifestation of the eternal battle between good and evil, just like the Jedi and the Sith. Thankfully, this concept has been preserved somewhat into canon.

Answer (score 2):

The [Ryloth system](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Ryloth_system) includes the planet [Ryloth](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Ryloth), which is the homeworld of the [Twi'lek](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Twi%27lek) species. The system also includes a moon with native life:

> Trees forty meters high stood sentinel around the pad. The arm-thick, ubiquitous vines so prevalent on the **moon** hung like a thousand nooses from the trees’ thick limbs. Screeches and howls from the **native** fauna punctuated the air. The towering jungle canopy blocked his view of Mors’s well-appointed command center, which had been built by Twi’lek forced labor.
>
> <sub>**[*Lords of the Sith*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Lords_of_the_Sith), p. 36**</sub>

Both the planet and moon are canon.

---

Credit to @WadCheber for the hint in one of his [comments](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/118031/do-any-systems-have-more-than-one-planetoid-capable-of-supporting-life#comment289391_118045) which reminded me of the moon's depiction in *Lords of the Sith*.

Answer (score 1):

NOTE: The answer to your question is YES.  What follows is by no means complete.  It is also by no means accurate, since I was basically just scrolling through a bunch of pages in Wookieepedia.

- [Yavin](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Yavin)
- [Tython](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Tython_system)
- [Churba](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Churba_system)
- [Regulan](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Regulan_system)
- [Colu](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Colu_system)
- [Saccoria](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Sacorrian_system) (Not sure if [Vo](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Vo), one of the planets, has had life on it.  Check it out)
- [Generis](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Generis_system)
- [Adega](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Adega_system)
- [Iskalon](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Iskalon_system)
- [Azurbani](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Azurbani_system)
- [Axum](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Axum_system)
- [Hapes](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Hapes_system)
- [Coruscant](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Coruscant_system)
- [Kalarba](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Kalarba_system)
- [Karthakk](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Karthakk_system)

Comment: Another reason this isn't complete--other than being really hard with bed wi-fi--is that I realized after doing this much that it was simply a yes/no question.

Comment: Don't forget when Darth Bane mounted the dxrel and flew between Dxun and Onderon after retrieving Freedom Nadd's holocron.